# how I can use cypress.screenshot() to capture my application's favicon

Tags: cypress

For UI Testing purpose I would like to take a screenshot of my application's favicon , I am using `cy.screenshot('Application', { capture: 'fullPage' })` but it is not capturing the favicon

Answer (score 3):

The favicon is displayed in the browser tab, so you can't grab it ***directly*** with `cy.screenshot()`, as the browser tab is out of scope for that command.

But Cypress can screenshot any *single* and *visible* element of the page, just by selecting it first.

For example, the logo on Cypress docs page

```js
cy.visit('https://docs.cypress.io/api/table-of-contents/')

cy.get('img[src^="/img/logo/cypress-logo"]')   // select the logo
  .first()                                    // only one can be used for screenshot
  .should('be.visible')                      // make sure it is visible
  .screenshot('logo')                       // write it to this file
```

**Logo screenshot**

[image]

---

#### Screenshot of favicon

If you want to get a screenshot of `favicon` which is displayed by default outside the web page, add it to the DOM first.

```js
cy.visit('https://docs.cypress.io/api/table-of-contents/')

cy.document()
  .find('head link[rel="icon"]')      // head link to favicon
  .first()                            // single element only
  .then($link => $link.attr('href'))  // extract the href
  .then(href => {
    cy.get('body')
      .then($body => {
        $body.empty()                                 // remove existing page
          .append(`<img id="favicon" src="${href}">`) // add favicon
      })
    cy.get('#favicon').screenshot('favicon')
  })
```

**Note** you don't *have* to remove existing page DOM, but if you don't then make sure the `favicon` is scrolled into view.

**Favicon screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can assert the `favicon` is available like so:

```js
it('assert favicon', () => {
 cy.visit('www.reactjs.org').document().its('head').find('link[rel="icon"]').should('have.attr', 'href').should('eq', '/favicon.ico')
});
```

The example above is using [React's official webpage](https://reactjs.org/) for the assertion, but you can customize the code for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the resolution but is there a way I can take a screenshot of the favicon by cy.screenshot()

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Maybe you grab the Favicon's `URL` & then visit the page & take screenshot of it. But it's a hack, I would say

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it seems that cypress is executing the screenshot before favicon has been loaded.
Have you tried just using a timeout before screenshot?

```
cy.wait(2500).then(cy.screenshot('Application', { capture: 'fullPage' }));
```